# Why am I unable to find the pid of a nano process that has a file being edited by root?

Tags: process, ubuntu-16.04, operating-system

I am trying to edit a file using nano and whenever I open the file for editing it gives me the following message:

```
File /path/to/file is being edited (by root with nano 2.5.3. PID 12345); continue?
```

Yet I can not find the process id in the list of running processes when I grep the pid or when I list all processes. I am unsure as to how to get to the bottom of this.
I'm on an ubuntu 16.04 VM.

Comment: Depending on what you did before there is probably a leftover/stale lock file and no actual process; see cross-dupes https://askubuntu.com/questions/730188/file-var-log-syslog-is-being-edited-message-in-nano and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287798/file-server-js-is-being-edited-by-root-with-nano-2-4-2-pid-xxxx-continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `ps aux | grep nano` and `pidof nano` to check if that process actually exists. If not try to find nano temporary file in the same location as your file. It should be name like that: file.save.

Comment: It turns out that there was a nano swap file at the same location. I found this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/730195 which gave me the clue.

Answer (score 1):

The following information should help. 
1. Are you using top to find the pid of the process. How are you trying to get it. 
2. Have your tried to get the process status. Try `ps -ef |grep *Pid shown*`

Update your question for further dig at it.

Answer (score 1):

use the command `ls -la` to find the temporary file. Its extension should be .swp remove that file and you should be able to open and edit the file again.

Comment: Vim uses .swp files, not nano.

Comment: I don't use vim, however nano created a .swp file. I have seen it multiple times.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. The accepted answer talks about a .save file, which there was, but that wasn't the culprit of the message. The hidden .swp file was.